# Error when trying make cleaned_data()! Django

Tags: python, django

Must be simple solution. But I do not see it. Please help me. Looks like 'gorod' is in request but when i trying cleaned_data() it gives me KeyError

```
KeyError at /ticket/

'gorod'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/ticket/
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

'gorod'

Exception Location:     C:\Documents and Settings\POLINOM\web\website\orders\views.py in SaveOrder2, line 93
Python Executable:  C:\Python26\python.exe
Python Version:     2.6.5


Traceback:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Documents and Settings\POLINOM\web\website\orders\views.py" in ticket
  136.             adr_form=MakeForm2(request)
File "C:\Documents and Settings\POLINOM\web\website\orders\views.py" in MakeForm2
  58.             SaveOrder2(request,form)
File "C:\Documents and Settings\POLINOM\web\website\orders\views.py" in SaveOrder2
  95.     gorod=form.cleaned_data['gorod']

Exception Type: KeyError at /ticket/
Exception Value: 'gorod'
```

My form:

```
class MumForm(AddressForm):
    CITY_CHOICES = (
                    (0,'August,11 - Washington, BlackCat'),
                    (1,'August,12 - Philadelphia, WorldLiveCafe'),
                    (2,'August,13 - New York, Irving Plaza'),
                    (3,'August,14 - Boston, Middle East'),
                    (4,'August,15 - Montreal, Cabaret Du Musee Juste Pour Rire'),
                    (5,'August,16 - Toronto, Mod club'),
                    (6,'August,17 - Cleveland, Beachland Tavern'),
                    (7,'August,18 - ------------------------'),
                    (9,'August,19 - ------------------------'),
                    (10,'August,20 - Atlanta, Masquerade'),
                    (11,'August,22 - Chicago, Empty Bottle'),
                    (12,'August,23 - Milwaukee, Shank Hall'),
                    (13,'August,24 - Minneapolis, Varsity (promoted by 1st Avenue)'),
                    (14,'August,25 - Winnipeg, Cowboys'),
                    (15,'August,27 - Edmonton, The Starlite Room'),
                    (16,'August,28 - Calgary, The Den'),
                    (17,'August,29 - Vancouver, Commodore Ballroom'),
                    (18,"August,31 - Seattle, Neumo's"),

                    (19,'September,01 - Portland, Howthorne Theatre'),
                    (20,'September,02 - San Francisco, Bottom Of The Hill'),
                    (21,'September,03 - Los Angeles, The Roxy'),
                    (22,'September,04 - Salt Lake City, Urban Lounge'),
                    (23,'September,05 - Denver, Bluebird Theatre'),
                    (24,'September,06 - Kansas City, The Record Bar'),
                    (25,'September,07 - Dallas, The Loft'),
                    (26,"September,08 - Austin, Emo's"),
        )
    gorod = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CITY_CHOICES, label="Выберите город в котором вы хотите пойти на концерт")
    note = forms.CharField(max_length=1500,label=u'Заметка',widget=forms.Textarea)
```

This is inherits from ather form which is:

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    address = forms.CharField(label=u"Адрес",max_length=200,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':60}))
    city = forms.CharField(label=u"Город",max_length=50,required=True)
    country = forms.ChoiceField(label=u"Страна",required=True,choices=COUNTRIES)
    state = forms.ChoiceField(label=u"Штат/Провинция",required=False, choices=StateProvince().get_all_states(), error_messages={'invalid_choice':u'нет среди допустимых значений. Пожалуйста, выберите правильный вариант'}) 
    zip = forms.CharField(label=u"Почтовый код",max_length=10,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':8}),required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label=u"Номер телефона",required=False)
```

there is two models which i'm working with:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=[
                    (1, 'Send'),
                    (0, 'Not_send'),                    
                ]
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=20)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Order by ' + self.user

class TicketProp(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order)
    note=models.CharField(max_length=1500)
gorod=models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

Comment: Please see the link on the traceback page which says "switch to copy and paste view", click it, then copy the resulting text here rather than the hugely long version you've pasted above.

Comment: Can you please show your code? Maybe the cause of the pb is no 'gorod' in your form?

Comment: The views.py code (at least the code involved in the stack trace) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your `AddressForm` class is missing the `gorod` field?  The form populates the `.cleaned_data` attribute (no `()` after the latter!-) based on the fields in the form; for example, in [the source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py) for the current `django.forms`, you'll see on line 274

```
for name, field in self.fields.items():
```

and it's in the body of the loop that the `.cleaned_data` dict is populated.

So what's your `AddressForm` code (and that of the model it presumably works with)...?

Comment: Yes it is missing. But i'm using child form which has two additional field. 'gorod' and 'note'. When I change them places than The error happen whith ather field.